# Add-DnsServerResourceRecord adds CNAME, but errors on adding A record

Tags: powershell, dns

Using Add-DnsServerResourceRecord I can add cname records, but when I attempt to add A records I get a permission denied error.

I'm trying to script dns record management with least privilege. The account I am using is a member of dns admins group, but not domain admins.

-----------------cut-----------------

```
Add-DnsServerResourceRecord -A -ZoneName cadpus.org -ComputerName pw-kdc1-p.cadpus.org -Name test-record10 -IPv4Address 10.0.203.251
```

> Add-DnsServerResourceRecord : Failed to create resource record
>   test-record10 in zone cadpus.org on server pw-kdc1-p.cadpus.org.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-DnsServerResourceRecord -A -ZoneName cadpus.org -ComputerName p ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (test-record10:root/Microsoft/...rResourceRecord) [Add-DnsServerResour
>   ceRecord], CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WIN32 5,Add-DnsServerResourceRecord

```
Add-DnsServerResourceRecord -Cname -ZoneName cadpus.org -ComputerName pw-kdc1-p.cadpus.org -Name test-record40 -HostNameAlias "www.cadpus.org"
```

-----------------cut-----------------

Queries for the cname record 'test-record40' work as expected.

Why would this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding them to DNSAdmins and DnsUpdateProxy